# Android Studio keeps using sdk 23 while I don't want it to

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

I have a little issue with an app. This is an app that I built several months ago, and it was working fine.

Yesterday, I had a change to do, made it, tried to compile it.. And I have this error :

```
D:\android\MyApp\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-v23\values-v23.xml
Error:(4) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
Error:(34) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

My build.gradle contains the follow : 
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 21
        buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'

```
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxxx"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 21
        versionName "2.5"
    }
}
```

I do NOT want to upgrade to SDK 23 (most common answer in similar threads), I want to understand what's wrong here, and why I have this error while I never use that god damn sdk.

Any clue ?

Comment: Could you show the whole `build.gradle` file?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/GAmQBjmi

Comment: I had a change to do??? what was that then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the reason is auto-update of Android Studio. If you have downloaded Build-tools rev.23 from the Sdk manager, try to delete it, then clean and rebuild project. Make sure that `compileSdkVersion`, `buildToolsVersion`, `targetSdkVersion` and `com.android.support:appcompat` match the same version.

**Update:** referring to updated build.gradle, the problem lies in using dynamic dependencies (`+` sign) which will force gradle to grab the latest library version. According to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html):

> (...) Using dynamic dependencies (for example, palette-v7:23.0.+)
>   can cause unexpected version updates and regression incompatibilities.
>   We recommend that you explicitly specify a library version (for
>   example, palette-v7:24.2.0)

Comment: Jackpot ! It was caused by the play service, I've just defined an old 6.x version, and it now works like a charm. Thanks a lot !